# Mongoose query document with multiple fileds including sub field Mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

Hi I have following model of a document in mongodb

Schema is

```
const ProductionsSchema=new Schema({
        name: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
        isActive: {type: Boolean, default: true},
        locations: [{
            name: {type: String},
            isActive : {type: Boolean, default: false}
        }],
        trackno: {type: String}
})
Productions:[{ 
       _id: 125,
        name: 'John Smith',
        locations: [{ name: 'Boston', isActive: true}]
        isActive: true,
        trackno: 2123
    }, 
        { 
       _id: 126,
        name: 'Moe Adam',
        locations: [{ name: 'Chicago', isActive: true}]
        isActive: true,
        trackno: 5663
    }, 
     { 
       _id: 126,
        name: 'Henry Noel',
        locations: [{ name: 'Houston', isActive: false}]
        isActive: true,
        trackno: 4552
    }, 
      { 
       _id: 128,
        name: 'Tim Johnson',
        locations: [{ name: 'Denver', isActive: true}]
        isActive: false,
        trackno: 6672
    }
```

]

I am trying to find list of with both isActive true

```
Productions.find({"isActive" : true , "locations.isActive": true}, (err, list)=>{
      if(err){
            callback(err);
            }
            callback(null, list)
        })
```

I am trying to write query so both isActive are true. In above sample data only first two records should be in the answer. But I keep getting all the records even ones with 'false' I even tried $elemMatch on locations.isActive still didnt work. 
Please let me know how I can fix this so that I only get result that contains only true values for both isActive.

Comment: `{ "isActive": true, "locations.isActive": true }`. That's an AND condition, which means BOTH.

Comment: I changed it to $and still same get both true and false records for locations.isActive

Comment: The people flagging it for duplicate are looking at answers for Mongo query, I am using mongoose for query which has different syntax and I already have looked at solutions on stackoverflow quite a bit

Comment: Show a document you think should match and one you think should not that you believe that query returns. And "the people"  ( me ) actually understand that there is **no difference**. Mongoose just passes through queries to MongoDB, and is not a language unto itself.

Comment: What I am asking for is like this "mongoose find multiple boolean conditions with sub array" if you search Stackoverflow for this there is no answer for it. You are misunderstanding my question ....I already spend few hours on stackoverflow searching other questions and tried alot of those solutions didnt work

Comment: I already very reasonably asked you to show some sample data demonstrating what is wrong and what you expect. Two small documents at most and it's not a big ask. If there's a brand new question, then I'll be happy to re-open it, or at least otherwise point you in the right direction, Explanations and examples belong in the question

Comment: ok I will edit question with sample data

Comment: So what is the issue? The query I gave you in the very first comment returns the first two documents. What are you expecting? I read your question as that is what you want, and that is exactly what is does. You don't need `$elemMatch` for a single condition on an array element. Only for multiple conditions on the same array element

Comment: I tried your solution i get null no record back. Than I removed "isActive: true and $and and just searched it locations.isActive: true and still displaying all the records. Problem is locations.isActive it just is not working

Comment: I saw you edited your question to replace `$or` with `$and`, but there's a "typo" in that code. Comment out your code and query, type in mine ( exactly as presented ) and run it, and if you believe it returns something different "copy & paste" the exact code you are running ( don't type it with more typo's ) and show us. Include the mongoose Schema for this collection as well, just in case you assigned the wrong types somewhere.

Comment: I tried your way and it gives me null and also I added the schema

Comment: Sorry but I do have to stop and eat occasionally. I'm at a loss as to what you could have done because this just works for the rest of the world. I can only show you a working example for you to compare from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the original comment explained, the only query conditions you need are:

```
{ isActive: true, "locations.isActive": true }
```

This is a basic AND condition, and you don't need any special operators just to verify a condition is met on a single property anywhere in an array, which is all you are asking.

Since this works exactly as expected, I can only think to show you a full working listing to use as a basis to work out what you are doing differently thus causing you to not get the same result as what is expected.

```
const { Schema } = mongoose = require('mongoose');

const uri = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/productions';
const opts = { useNewUrlParser: true };

mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);
mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true);
mongoose.set('debug', true);

const productionSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  isActive: { type: Boolean, default: true },
  locations: [{
    name: String,
    isActive: { type: Boolean, default: false }
  }],
  trackno: Number
})

const Production = mongoose.model('Production', productionSchema);

const data =
[
    {
        name: 'John Smith',
        locations: [{ name: 'Boston', isActive: true}],
        isActive: true,
        trackno: 2123
    },
        {
        name: 'Moe Adam',
        locations: [{ name: 'Chicago', isActive: true}],
        isActive: true,
        trackno: 5663
    },
     {
        name: 'Henry Noel',
        locations: [{ name: 'Houston', isActive: false}],
        isActive: true,
        trackno: 4552
    },
    {
        name: 'Tim Johnson',
        locations: [{ name: 'Denver', isActive: true}],
        isActive: false,
        trackno: 6672
    }
];

const log = data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2));

(async function() {

  try {
    const conn = await mongoose.connect(uri, opts);

    // clean data
    await Promise.all(
      Object.entries(conn.models).map(([k, m]) => m.deleteMany())
    );

    // set up
    await Production.insertMany(data);

    // Query
    let query = { isActive: true, "locations.isActive": true };
    let results = await Production.find(query);

    log(results);


  } catch(e) {
    console.error(e)
  } finally {
    mongoose.disconnect()
  }

})()
```

Which outputs the two expected documents:

```
Mongoose: productions.deleteMany({}, {})
Mongoose: productions.insertMany([ { isActive: true, _id: 5c7f7e9367daed19d6773e9b, name: 'John Smith', locations: [ { isActive: true, _id: 5c7f7e9367daed19d6773e9c, name: 'Boston' } ], trackno: 2123, __v: 0 }, { isActive: true, _id: 5c7f7e9367daed19d6773e9d, name: 'Moe Adam', locations: [ { isActive: true, _id: 5c7f7e9367daed19d6773e9e, name: 'Chicago' } ], trackno: 5663, __v: 0 }, { isActive: true, _id: 5c7f7e9367daed19d6773e9f, name: 'Henry Noel', locations: [ { isActive: false, _id: 5c7f7e9367daed19d6773ea0, name: 'Houston' } ], trackno: 4552, __v: 0 }, { isActive: false, _id: 5c7f7e9367daed19d6773ea1, name: 'Tim Johnson', locations: [ { isActive: true, _id: 5c7f7e9367daed19d6773ea2, name: 'Denver' } ], trackno: 6672, __v: 0 } ], {})
Mongoose: productions.find({ isActive: true, 'locations.isActive': true }, { projection: {} })
[
  {
    "isActive": true,
    "_id": "5c7f7e9367daed19d6773e9b",
    "name": "John Smith",
    "locations": [
      {
        "isActive": true,
        "_id": "5c7f7e9367daed19d6773e9c",
        "name": "Boston"
      }
    ],
    "trackno": 2123,
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "isActive": true,
    "_id": "5c7f7e9367daed19d6773e9d",
    "name": "Moe Adam",
    "locations": [
      {
        "isActive": true,
        "_id": "5c7f7e9367daed19d6773e9e",
        "name": "Chicago"
      }
    ],
    "trackno": 5663,
    "__v": 0
  }
]
```